# Задать отличный от корневого каталога каталог задачи

Tags: c#, scheduler

Программно создаю задание:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
        using (var ts = new TaskService(host, "администратор", "local", "pass"))
        {
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            var tr = new BootTrigger() { Enabled = true };
            td.RegistrationInfo.Date = DateTime.Now;
            td.RegistrationInfo.Author = "Index Admin";
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Создано Index Admin";
            td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
            td.Principal.UserId = "SYSTEM";
            td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
            td.Settings.MultipleInstances = TaskInstancesPolicy.IgnoreNew;
            td.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = true;
            td.Settings.Hidden = false;
            td.Settings.Enabled = true;
            td.Settings.IdleSettings.RestartOnIdle = false;
            td.Settings.IdleSettings.StopOnIdleEnd = false;
            td.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = false;
            td.Settings.RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = false;
            td.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = true;
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(TaskTarget, WorkDirectory));
            td.Triggers.Add(tr);
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(staleName, td);
        }
```

Вопрос как задать не корневую директорию(не в "/" планировщика), а произвольную.

И можно ли из этого инстанса сразу запустить таск?

Comment: Абсольтный путь туда разве не вписывается?

Comment: Блин, друг, точно. Что я к этой RootFolder докопался. `ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($@"Stale\{staleName}", td);` - точно! Спасибо.